# Создание своего сниппета в Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, сниппет

Цель такая: есть код

```js
const testItem = 42;
```

Я выделяю название переменной `testItem` двойным кликом, далее вызываю сниппет сочетанием клавиш, допустим двойное нажатие shift.

В итоге хочу получить такой результат

```js
const testItem = 42;
console.log('testItem ', testItem)
```

То есть, что бы под моей искомой строкой добавилась строка:

```js
console.log('testItem ', testItem)
```

Я пробовал варианты вроде

```js
    {
        "key": "shift shift",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "console.log('${TM_CURRENT_LINE}')\n${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}"
        }
    }
```

Но результат не тот который ожидается